# Converting UNIX timestamp to date?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRQxMYoCOuI) by sentdex regarding converting UNIX timestamps to matplotlib-recognised dates.
I'm still new to this and while I understand the examples given in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) since they are pretty simple, I do not understand why np.vectorize is used in this case:

```
date_convert = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)
date = date_convert(date)
```

1. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), doesn't dt.datetime.fromtimestamp need 1 argument? No argument was passed here though.
2. What is the point of calling np.vectorize on dt.datetime.fromtimestamp though? Perhaps I still don't quite grasp the concept of this function.
3. How come date_convert can accept an argument on the second line when it wasn't defined as a function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for the patience!

Comment: np.vectorize takes a callable function or method and converts it to a new function similar to using `map` which accepts an array as input. Because `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` accepts only a single input, you have to either use the function in a loop, use `map` or np.vectorize to process an array. If you are using pandas, you can use `apply(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)` on a dataframe.

Comment: Note that functions in Python are first-class - they can be passed around, even to other functions. Using ``dt.datetime.fromtimestamp`` instead of ``dt.datetime.fromtimestamp()`` allows to pass the function ``dt.datetime.fromtimestamp`` into the function ``np.vectorize``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `np.vectorize` does is basically make the `datetime` functions usable on arrays instead of single values.

If you use `dt.datetime.fromtimestamp` you are right that it only takes 1 argument but it also only works on 1 value. So the following example which has 2 dates will bring up an error.

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

dates = np.array([13444,9000009])
dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(dates)
```

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

However using `np.vectorize` creates a new function called `date_convert` that does the same thing as `dt.datetime.fromtimestamp` but allows multiple values like in an array.

```
date_convert = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)

dates = np.array([13444,9000009])
date_convert(dates)

#returns:
#array([datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 20, 44, 4),
#       datetime.datetime(1970, 4, 14, 21, 0, 9)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 4):

To make this more transparent, let's create our own vectorizer.

```
import datetime as dt

data = [1326244364, 1326844366, 1327245361]

def myfromtimestampfunction(timestamp):
    return dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

def myvectorizer(input_func):

    def output_func(array_of_numbers):
        return [input_func(a) for a in array_of_numbers]

    return output_func

date_convert =  myvectorizer(myfromtimestampfunction)
dates = date_convert(data)

print(dates)
```

`myvectorizer` takes in a function, and outputs a function. The input function can only take single numbers as input. The output function can take an iterable.

With this it may be easier to understand that

1. You do not call the input function, you just pass it to the vectorizer.
2. `myfromtimestampfunction(data)` would fail, because `data` is a list, but `myfromtimestampfunction` expects a single number.
3. `date_convert` ***is*** a function, namely the `output_func` from the vectorizer. It hence can take an argument as input.